# Rank dataframe in python pandas by dense rank and replace non-consecutive numbers in column with consecutive numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to rank a dataframe in ascending order of score and if found two scores are the same, then assign the same rank. I am currently using the following method,

`df['IAbsRank'] = df['IAbs'].rank(ascending=0,method='dense')`

The original file I am given to sort out the ranking for, is ran through some python script (this is after the ranking is perfomed), which for reasons not relevant here, removes a lot of the rows, which results in the columns  `IAbs`, `IRel` missing a lot of their consecutive (and duplicates if the ranking is the same, i.e. 1,2,2,3,4,5,5) numbers.

I have intentionally omitted several columns, from the original dataframe, which would have been displayed on the left of the posted ones below.

The important columns I want to rank are `IAbs`, `IRel.` Not sure if it is relevant, but each column has between about 3,000 rows, which I am omitting here.

`IAbs        IAbsRank   IRel    IRelRank
69102933.3   1          30      10
43261866.7   3          6.1     56
36259200     6          1.8     317
35766400     7          1.9     286
34404266.7   8          7.6     47
29296000     11         2.6     178`

Fyi, in the python script itself, the ranking is done prior to the file being saved in its final csv format, i.e.

`df['IAbsRank'] = df['IAbs'].rank(ascending=0,method='dense')`
`df['IAbsRank'].to_csv(out_fn)`
`df['IRelRank'] = df['IRel'].rank(ascending=0,method='dense')`
`df.sort_values(by="IAbsRank", ascending=True, inplace=True)`
`df[df['Select'] == True].to_csv(out_fn, index=False, float_format="%.1f")`

Where `True` represents a condition the python scripts looks for in all the rows. As mentioned above, rows which **do not** satisfy this condition, are removed.

Where and how, in the python script, can I re-rank the columns, so as to correct for the rows which have been removed, so I end up for example, with the ranking columns having the results displayed in increasing number, from top to bottom, with no numbers being skipped?

Comment: Hi @coldspeed, I have since updated my question with more relevant info. I have tried what you suggested and it works if open the file again, process the ranking and save it for a second time. For the second time ranking, I am using the following code, which forces me to change the column headings, for example, from `IncreaseAbsRank` to `IncreaseAbsRank2`.  

The code is:

`df['IncreaseAbsRank2'] = df['IncreaseAbsRank'].rank(ascending=0,method='dense')`  
`df.sort_values(by="IncreaseAbsRank2", ascending=True, inplace=True)`  
Is there a way to keep the original column headings?

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed